# Entity Framework Core 3.0: Modify configured Global Query during runtime

Tags: ef-core-3.0

I've following requirement:

During the model configuration, I create a QueryFilter for an Entity

`var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<TBaseTable>().HasQueryFilter(r => r.UserId == CurrentUserId)`

So during runtime in some cases the `CurrentUserId` changes. But my QueryFilter does not get refreshed. The filter criteria still are working with the old UserId value, which I had during the configuration. How do i modify the my QueryFiler, which was set during the configuration? If I'm right then the whole model is already cached and will not be reinitialized. Any ideas about that?

Comment: What is `CurrentUserId`? What is `TBaseTable`? Where is the fluent code located? I'm asking because if `CurrentUserId` is a property/field of the derived db context, the code is located inside `OnModelCreating` override of that context, and `TBaseTable` is a concrete entity type, the filter will be dynamic and work as expected.

Comment: CurrentUserId is provided from an global class instance. It is not a property value of an entity. So the query will use the Id from the first user which is configuring the DbContext. This works exactly how i expected. Afterwards there is the possibility to switch the CurrentUser. So the CurrentUserId will change, but the query still seems to use the value which was provided on startup.

As it looks now, i have to redeclare the global query filter. But I've no idea how i can do that. After the configuring of the model has been completed.

Comment: Global filters cannot be redeclared. But they can be made dynamic by using properties/methods/fields of the db context. See the `TenantId` example in [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) documentation. So make sure `CurrentUserId` is a property of your context - the property getter can still return a value from some global class instance. The difference is that EF Core will reevaluate the property anytime it needs to apply the filter, rather than just once at the time the model is created.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed.
Providing the filter values through a DbContext property solved my problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to declare `CurrentUserId` as a property on your `DbContext` class - the property getter can still return a value from a global class instance.

Global filters can be made dynamic by using properties/methods/fields of the db context. See the TenantId example in [Global Query Filters](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) documentation.

(Since I needed to read the comments to find the answer to your question I rephrased the comment as provided by "Ivan Stoev Oct 8 '19 at 15:34" and posted it as an answer)